# Scroll content + scroll popover doesn't work properly in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4, popover

I put terms and condition in popover to show it for users.
When popover present part of content visible  not all content and can not scroll to show all content.

After searching I find this issue  [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16910). and try their solution but not work

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue via adding all content in
`<ion-list>`  inside `<ion-content>`